# unexpected token: :(colon) in Hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql

I'm trying to do the following code, but i get the `unexpected token: : near line 1` error which refer to `ord.date_out::date`. Here is my code

```
@Query(value="select new com.ameerarestapi.wrapper.report.SummaryPeriodicSales(sto.name, sum(odi.subtotal_price), sum(odi.qty), ((sum(odi.subtotal_price))/(sum(odi.qty))), ord.date_out::date) "
                 + "from OrderDetailItem odi "
                 + "left join odi.order as ord "
                 + "left join ord.store as sto "
                 + "where ord.store.principle = :principle and ord.orderStatus IN :orderstatus and ord.dateOut between :date1 and :date2 and ord.voidStatus = :voidStatus "
                 + "group by sto.name, ord.date_out::date ")
List<SummaryPeriodicSales> getReportDaily(@Param("principle") Principle principle,@Param("orderstatus") List<OrderStatus> orderstatus,@Param("date1") Date date1,@Param("date2") Date date2,@Param("voidStatus") byte voidStatus);
```

I'm using postgre database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the standard [`CAST()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-functions) operator instead:

```
CAST(ord.date_out AS date)
```